# uniform continuity - Using Lipshitz always

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

Question, is it possible to prove each question regarding uniform continuity with Lipshitz? I am having problem with this subject and can only answer be using Lipshitz. but I see there are some problems i can't manage to answer.
Let's say I must prove a function is uniform continuity on $(1,\infty)$ or like $(0,1)$ and such...
I never understand the meaning of the range while doing uniform continuity... just answering it using the Lipshitz (without thinking basically).
A month ago, I had a test - went really bad. anyway, there was a question:
prove $f(x)=x-cos^3\sqrt(x$) is uniform continuity at: $[0,\infty)$. I tried answering using Lipshitz, but I needed to prove first the derivative is blocked at $[1,\infty)$.
Anyway, you understand what i mean? Using Lipshitz, can I answer every question using Lipshitz? or I have to use Epsilion,delta \ other idea to solve?
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: What does “using Lipshitz” mean?

Comment: Hi, Lipshitz i mean the Lipshitz proof with the K, the constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a problem in which you are supposed to prove that a certain function $f$ is uniformly continuous and if $f$ is *not* Lipshitz then, clearly, you cannot use the fact that the function is Lipshitz, since it is not. An example would be$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[0,\infty)&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\sqrt x.\end{array}$$

Comment: Ahh.. I thought I could get away with using lipshitz... I dont know what to do... I cant manage to study uniform continuity.. do you have any tips maybe on how to answer such questions? without Lipshitz.
And thanks for the answer, you pretty much answered me ( in a few mins I will upload the V when possible )

Comment: It is useful to know that every continuous function from an interval $[a,b]$ into $\Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous. And the function $f$ from my answer is uniformly continuous since its restriction to $[0,1]$ is continuous, and therefore uniformly continuous, and its restriction to $[1,\infty)$ is Lipschitz, and therefore it is also uniformly continuous.

Comment: hmm, about restriction to $[0,1]$ - see, thats my problem. why is there a restriction? why cant I just do Lipshitz from $[0,\infty)$? why from $[1,\infty)$ it is lipshitz?

Comment: Do you have some problem with the word “restriction”? All that I am saying is that $\sqrt x$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and that therefore it is uniformly continuous there. And it is Lipschitz n $[1,\infty)$ because $x,y\geqslant1\implies\bigl|\sqrt x-\sqrt y\bigr|\leqslant\frac12|x-y|$.

Comment: Yea, but my point is why Isn't it Lipshitz on $[0,1]$, that is my problem, why are there domains where Lipshitz will not work? why do I have to separate, that is my downfall on this subject ( the reason I failed my test :( )

Comment: If $f$ was Lipshtiz on $[0,1]$, there would be some number $K>0$ such that, whenever $x,y\in[0,1]$, we would have $\bigl|\sqrt x-\sqrt y\bigr|\leqslant K|x-y|$. In particular, if $x\in[0,1]$, then $\sqrt x\leqslant Kx$. But this would imply that, if $x\in(0,1]$, $\frac1{\sqrt x}\leqslant K$. This is impossible, since $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1{\sqrt x}=\infty$.

Comment: I see, thanks alot!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.